# If an undergrad maths student publishes a paper in renowned journals, then will he be able to get chance in top universities?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-undergraduate

My grades are average and I want to study mathematics in top institutions like cambridge, princeton etc. If I am able to publish a paper in mathematics in high impact journals, then will it be possible to pursue a research career from best universities?

Comment: If it is ground breaking enough you may even be promoted instantly to professor. See Liu Lu and the Seetapun conjecture.

Comment: Not to be discouraging, but even though the answer to the question is yes (assuming you made a significant intellectual contribution to the paper and didn't simply help a faculty coauthor in routine ways), doing this is several orders of magnitude more difficult than getting good grades in undergrad.